# Are the stalks of the ideal sheaf of Y generated by rational functions that are zero or undefined on Y?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be an irreducible algebraic variety and $Y$ an irreducible closed subvariety not equal to $X$. Let $I$ be the ideal sheaf of $Y$ in $X$. Is it true that for every point $P \in X$, the stalk $I_P$ is generated over $O_{X, P}$ by elements $[U, f] ∈ O_{X, P}$ such that for every $Q \in Y$, considering $f$ as a rational function, $f$ is either zero or undefined at $Q$?

##### What I have tried so far:

The case where $P$ is in $Y$ is clear.

The claim is true if $X$ is quasiprojective: since we can choose an affine open $U$ in $X$ that contains $P$ and a point of $Y$, it suffices to prove the claim for $X$ affine. In this case, we can choose $f$ to be a polynomial that is zero on $Y$ such that $f(P)$ is non-zero. Since $f$ is a unit in $O_{X, P}$, it generates the whole of $O_{X, P}$.

Similarly, the claim is true if for every two points $P$ and $Q$ in $X$, we can find an affine open subset that contains both $P$ and $Q$.

Also, the claim is true if and only if the following holds: for every two points $P$ and $Q$ in $X$, there exists a rational function $f$ that is non-zero at $Q$ and either zero or undefined at $P$.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that $\mathscr{I}$ is the kernel of the map $\phi: \mathcal{O}_X \to i_*\mathcal{O}_Y$. As such, if $f_p := [U, f] \in \mathscr{I}_p$, then $\phi_p(f_p) = [U, \phi_U(f)] = [U, 0] =  0$.

The map $\phi$ here is how you go from regular functions on $X$ to those on $Y$; it is essentially formalizing the process of restricting the functions to $Y$ as you'll see below.

In particular, $i_*\mathcal{O}_Y(U) = \mathcal{O}_Y(Y \cap U)$ so that $\phi_U(f)$ is the zero element of $\mathcal{O}_Y(Y \cap U)$. Hence $\phi_U(f)$ is either a rational function on $Y$ which is zero where it is defined, or $U \cap Y = \emptyset$ so $\phi_U(f)$ is defined nowhere. We note that if $p \in Y$, the latter possibility is not possible.

I hope this helps.

Comment: > or ∩=∅ so  is defined nowhere.

A counter-example to this part: choose  such that ∩=∅ and choose  to be the constant zero-function.

Comment: I was referring to $f$ as viewed as a function on $Y$. It would probably be more clear to say that $\phi_U(f)$ is 'defined nowhere' as a section of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ over the emptyset. I edited the answer to reflect that. Any rational function defined outside of $Y$ will be in $\mathscr{I}$ for this reason.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not quite convinced. For example, the constant function $1$ is defined on every $U$ that does not intersect $Y$, and it generates the stalk $\mathscr{I}_p$ for every $p$ not in $Y$. But the constant function $1$ is not zero nor undefined at every point of $Y$.

What I am asking is if there exist functions $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ that generate $\mathscr{I}_p$ such that all the functions $f_1, \ldots, f_k$ are either zero or undefined at every point in $Y$.